# Дождаться окончания функции в отдельном потоке

Tags: android, многопоточность, firebase, firebase-database, android-threads

Есть новостное приложение, которое хранит данные в Firebase (база новостей лежит там). Для того, чтобы вытащить новости из базы, надо поставить на определенную отсылку к ней (будь то child, child child-a и т.д.) listener.

**Проблема:** Функции внутри listener-a выводятся в отдельный поток. К примеру, после того, как я подгрузил новости из Firebase базы, я хочу занести их в базу данных на устройстве. Вот только я не знаю подгрузились ли уже все новости, а поставить `thread.join()` на функцию тоже не могу.

**Вопрос:** как дождаться завершения всех потоков внутри потока? Если child-овские потоки создавал не я. Или же как дождаться завершения функции?

Answer (score 1):

Для параллельных запросов вариант с [CountDownLatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) (можно еще rxJava использовать, но там не так наглядно получится, хотя и короче).

```
    void onClick(View v){ // клик в активити
        new Thread(new Runnable(){ // запускаем новый поток, чтоб не морозить UI
           void run(){
               int requestCount = 5; // нужно запустить пять запросов
               final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(requestCount); // "блокиратор"
               for(int i=0; i<requestCount; i++){ 
                    // делаем 5 параллельных запросов
                    srv.getPage(i, new Callback<PageData>() {  
                        @Override
                        public void success(final PageData page, Response response) {
                           // страница получена
                           runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
                               void run(){
                                   updateUI(page); обновляем UI с полученными данными, возвращаем из в UI-поток
                               }
                           });
                           latch.countDown(); //уменьшаем счетчик блокиратора
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                           // если надо оповещаем об ошибке
                           runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
                               void run(){
                                   showUIError(error);
                               }
                           });
                           latch.countDown(); //уменьшаем счетчик блокиратора
                        }
                   });
                   try {
                       latch.await(); // поток ждет, пока счетчик не дойдет до нуля
                   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
                   // Оповещаем UI о конце загрузки
                   runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){ 
                       void run(){
                           loadingFinished();
                       }
                   });
               }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Для последовательных запросов достаточно делать в цикле синхронные запросы, по окончании цикла оповестить ui.

ЗЫ Писал в окне ответа, могут быть опечатки.